# Skewed data: choosing the average or median

Tags: statistics, average, median

**Goal:**

The data below shows (in order) the `date`, `median`, `average`, `high` and `low` of a survey taken on each of the dates. Out of the data set, the `average` or `median` **of each row** will be used for future analysis.

```
Date        Med (K)     Avg (K)     High (K)    Low (K)
8/14/2003   73          74          81          65
8/21/2003   105         109         90          135
8/28/2003   70          70          80          58
09/04/2003  73          72          82          59
09/11/2003  91          99          78          130
9/18/2003   95          95          109         78
```

**Q1.** Based off of the columns of data available, is there enough data to determine whether or not **each row** is `skewed` or `symmetrical`, and to thus base on whether to take the `average` or `median` for that row?

My idea was that maybe this could be achieved by observing where the `average` and `median` fall between `high` and `low`.

**Q2.** For rows where the `median` and `average` are close together, for example, `row 1` where the `median = 73K` and `average = 74K`, which of these two values could be chosen for further calculations?

Being new to statistics, the language or understanding of methods in this question may be inaccurate, so apologies if this is the case.

Comment: For analysis, it's good to take both measures. However, for skewed distribution, the median is often a preferred as the measure of central tendency because the mean is not usually in the middle of the distribution.

Comment: @EddyPiedad Thanks for your reply. So determine if the data is skewed, would this be when the `avg` and `median` are substantially different from each other (e.g. rows 2 and 5)?

Comment: Yes. If mode = median = mean for a symmetrical data set, mode < median < mean for a positively skewed data set, mode > median > mean for a negatively skewed data. sethttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Relationship_of_mean_and_median

Comment: You can even quantify skewness using Fisher's moment coefficient of skewness or sample skewness.

Comment: That's great, thanks for your help.